# How Connect Multi Struct in Header Using C?

Tags: c, struct

How Connect Multi Struct in Header Using C?

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"    
int main()
{
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

main.h:

```
struct Mother;
struct Sub;
/////////////////////////////
struct Mother{
    sub item;
};
struct Sub{
    mother item;
};
/////////////////////////////
typedef struct Mother mother;
typedef struct Sub sub;
```

---

$ gcc -O3 -o output main.c

```
In file included from main.c:2:0:
main.h:5:2: error: unknown type name ‘sub’
  sub item;
  ^~~
main.h:8:2: error: unknown type name ‘mother’
  mother item;
  ^~~~~~
```

how can fix problem and error of 'struct Mother' and 'struct Sub'?

---

NEW Update:
i also try header as:

```
struct Mother;
struct Sub;
/////////////////////////////
struct Mother{
    Sub *item;
};
struct Sub{
    Mother *item;
};
/////////////////////////////
typedef struct Mother Mother;
typedef struct Sub Sub;
```

but also error.

Comment: Your first proble is a syntax problem: `struct Mother` isn't magically `mother`, note the `struct` keyword and the case sensitivity. Your second problem is a spatial problem: You can't put mother into sub and then sub into mother. Use pointers to these structures for that.

Comment: good,may submit a sample code like my code with no problem?

Comment: @CPerfomance see my answer. You have to move the `typedef`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** First of all, write your `typedef`s before the declaration of your `struct`s. Right now, you refer to `mother` and `sub` *before* `typedef`ing them, so it is expected to get an error.

**2.** Then, instead of declaring a `struct Mother` in `struct Sub` and vice versa, declare a *pointer* to `struct`, like this :

```
struct Mother;
struct Sub;

typedef struct Mother mother;
typedef struct Sub sub;

struct Mother{
    sub *item;
};
struct Sub{
    mother *item;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mate, you can't make that.

Why do you need a **Mother** in your **Sub** if your **Mother** already have a **Sub** entry ?

Just think about this :

```
Mother A;
Sub B;

A.item = B;
B.item = A;
```

So you can access to B by A like this:

```
B.A;
```

and you can access to A by B like this:

```
A.B;
```

So you can make chains like this :

```
A.B.A.B.A.B  //and so on ...
```

There's maybe a way to compile your code, but I'm trying to show you the paradox here, there's no point to do that

You can do this if needed :

```
struct Sub
{
  int   motherId; //this refer to the Mother.Id;     
};

struct Mother
{
  int    id; //Stocked in Sub struct                 
  struct Sub subs;// if needed you can do an array   
};

typedef struct Mother mother;
typedef struct Sub sub;
```

(this will compile)